# VLC can't load simple openCV video filter

Tags: c++, opencv, video, vlc

I've wrote a simple opencv test video filter for VLC. Built it with no errors but on VLC launch it gets me:

> core libvlc warning: cannot load module
>   `/vlc_build/vlc/modules/.libs/libnormalization_cpp_plugin.so'
>   (/vlc_build/vlc/modules/.libs/libnormalization_cpp_plugin.so:
>   undefined symbol: _ZTVN2cv11_InputArrayE)

I'm using OpenCV 3.0.0-beta and VLC media player 3.0.0-git Vetinari (revision 2.2.0-git-2564-gc8549fb)

Here is the main function to transform frame-by-frame video:

```
static picture_t *FilterNormalizeOpenCV( filter_t *p_filter, picture_t *p_pic ){
    IplImage* p_img;
    int i_planes = 0;
    CvPoint pt1, pt2;
    filter_sys_t *p_sys = p_filter->p_sys;

    Mat frame, frame_hist_equalized;
    vector<Mat> channels;

    //picture_t to IplImage without segmentation fault
    p_img = cvCreateImageHeader( cvSize( p_pic->p[0].i_pitch, p_pic->p[0].i_visible_lines ),
        IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    cvSetData( p_img, p_pic->p[0].p_pixels, p_pic->p[0].i_pitch );
    frame = cvarrToMat(p_img);

    cvtColor(frame, frame_hist_equalized, COLOR_BGR2YCrCb);

    IplImage* z_img = new IplImage(frame_hist_equalized);
    cvGetRawData( z_img, (uchar**)&p_pic->p[0].p_pixels, NULL, NULL );

    return p_pic;
}
```

I guess, it fails on cvtColor() function call and it is possible of wrong vlc-image(p_pic) to opencv(Mat frame) processing. I couldn't find any reasonable solutions on the web.

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: Don't use the C-Api with OpenCV 3.0.0, it was deprecated a long time ago and will only cause many, many problems.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The mistake was in incorrect linking openCV libs during vlc build.